# F# block arguments

Tags: f#

C# has anonymous delegates. So I can write:

```
public vois foo(string d, Action t){
    t();
}
```

In ruby:

```
def foo d
  yield
end
```

How to do the same in F#? Prefered syntax is:

```
foo "dfdfdf" { do something here }
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you didn't make your point clear. Your foo function is different in your c# and ruby implementation. So what is your question about? You don't know how to pass a delegate to a function and execute it?

Comment: They actually the same. They are functions that accept two arguments. First is string d and second is executable code. For C# example this is done with Action (so it accept anonymous methods). For ruby, just implicit block execution (yield will execute something that you will pass as second argument)

Comment: what a weird use of "yield" keywork :). Now I understand.

Comment: yes it bit different http://blog.msc.se/blogs/index.php/dynamic/2008/10/28/ruby-block-arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example isn't an anonymous method -- it's just passing and calling through a delegate (which might refer to a named or an anonymous method).  To do this in F#, just provide and call a function argument:

```
let foo n f = f n

let square n = n * n
let result = foo 123 square
printfn "%A" result
```

To create the equivalent of an anonymous method in F#, use the fun keyword:

```
let result2 = foo 123 (fun n -> n * n)
```

Comment: Sure it not. It razer consumer of the anonymous method. Anyways, thank you for solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article about [Higher Order Functions in F#](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions).  Higher Order Functions are functions which accept other functions as arguments, and sound like the concept you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

```
open System

// create a function that expects an Action delegate and executes it
let foo (actionDelegate:Action) (s:String) = actionDelegate.Invoke();

// create a function that meets Action delegate
let ActionFunction param = Console.Write("Action in action")

// call foo passing ActionFunction
foo (new Action(ActionFunction)) "my string"
```

Comment: well, I am not looking how to use .NET Action. This is why I also refereing to the ruby example.